# How to continuously update notification even when app is not running?

Tags: android

I am trying to implement a timer with notification that cannot be swiped away by user. I want to continuously update the timer's time.

I know there are a lot of similar question online. But a lot of them discuss using handler, or a service. All of these won't run when my app is not being used by the user. AlarmManager doesn't work because i want to update every x millisecond.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a foreground service

> A foreground service performs some operation that is noticeable to the
>   user. For example, an audio app would use a foreground service to play
>   an audio track. Foreground services must display a Notification.
>   Foreground services continue running even when the user isn't
>   interacting with the app.

There is a limit on how frequently you can update the notifications as well, every MS will cause problems.